# HTTPS breaks on external clients when redirecting HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: apache, ssl, redirect, https, ssl-certificate

I'm using Apache 2.4 on Windows Server 2008 R2.

On the server itself and all company-internal clients, HTTP works fine and HTTPS works fine.  Redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS also works fine.

On clients outside the company (i.e., a home machine), HTTP works fine and HTTPS works fine.  However, redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS is broken.

The error message that appears is as follows: **ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID**.

When this error occurs, if I look at the details of the certificate, they indicate that the certificate is issued to "localhost.localdomain."  I haven't found that domain name in my Apache config files. The details also say that the organization of the certificate is our internet service provider and was issued on May 7, 2011 and expires on March 4, 2021.  None of these certificate details are true of our actual certificate.  Our certificate was issued by Digicert and expires in 2019.

When I use SSL Labs to diagnose, the test doesn't even fully run and the following error message appears:

```
Certificate name mismatch
Try these other domain names (extracted from the certificates):

    localhost.localdomain
```

These are my VirtualHost configs:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com:80
ServerAlias example.com:80

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [NE,L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.example.com:443
ServerAlias example.com:443
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "C:\https\star_example_com.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\https\star_example.com.key"
SSLCertificateChainFile "C:\https\DigiCertCA.crt"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [NE,L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

I have also tried redirecting using the following redirect command, but the same thing happens:

```
Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
```

Comment: It sounds like you installed the wrong certificate.  Are you sure that the file(s) you got from Digicert are in the locations listed in httpd.conf ?  Have you stopped and restarted apache?

Comment: 1. Yes, the certs are the ones from Digicert.  In fact, HTTPS fully works and shows our exact certificate internally *and* externally.  It just doesn't work externally once I enable the redirect.  Only then is when the unknown/mysterious certificate appears.

2. Yes, I have stopped and started the Apache service numerous times trying to diagnose this.

Answer (score 0):

So, we figured it out.  It has very little to do with HTTPS or the redirect.

We have a website failover server that kicks in if it detects that our main site is offline or malfunctioning.

Well, apparently, the failover logic detected 301/302 redirects as failures.  The mysterious certificate was being served by the failover server.

We had to change the failover logic to no longer see redirects as failures.